# TypeError: Cannot Read Property of Undefined Even Though I Defined It

Tags: javascript

I'm a beginner to JavaScript. I've looked through a few questions on here regarding "TypeError: ... undefined even though the property is defined" but their examples are either too dense for me to grasp or they realize they've incorrectly assigned something downstream. Here I think my example is quite simple, and I don't think I've incorrectly assigned anything.

I've defined position in my class MoveableObjects and when I call player = new MoveableObject(position, other params ...) I don't get any errors.

When I change this to player = new Sprite(position, other params ...) where Sprite extends MoveableObjects and then try to call a function inside Sprite it tells me position.x is undefined. I put console.log(player) immediately after the declaration and it does in fact show position as undefined, but I don't understand why it does since I've clearly defined it.

Here is the constructor of MoveableObjects

```
class MoveableObject {
    
    constructor({ colorRGB, width, height, position, velocity}) {
        this.width = width;
        this.height = height;
        this.position = position;
        this.velocity = velocity;
        this.colorRGB = colorRGB;


        // If the side of the object is touching or beyond the side of the canvas it is flagged as bounded.
        this.inUpLimit = false;
        this.inDownLimit = false;
        this.inLeftLimit = false;
        this.inRightLimit = false;

        // Translate the velocity into directional words
        this.movingLeft = false;
        this.movingRight = false;
        this.movingUp = false;
        this.movingDown = false;
    }
```

Here is the constructor of Sprite and the draw() function it uses.

```
// Sprite represents moveable objects with an animated image.
class Sprite extends MoveableObject {
    
    constructor({ imageSrc, numRows = 1, numCols = 1, spacing = 0, margin = 0, animationSpeed = 10, position, velocity}) {
        
        super(position, velocity)
        
        this.image = new Image()                             // Image can be a single image or a spritesheet.
        this.image.src = imageSrc
        this.numRows = numRows                               // # animation sequences in the spritesheet
        this.numCols = numCols                               // # frames in an animation sequence
        this.spacing = spacing                               // # pixels between each frame
        this.margin = margin                                 // # pixels between image border and sprite border. Vertical and horizontal margins should be equal.
        this.animation = new Object()
        this.animation.speed = animationSpeed                // # times draw function is called before the next frame in the animation sequence is called.
        this.animation.counter = 0                           // # times the draw function has been called
        this.animation.enabled = false                       // Whether or not the animation sequence is currently running
        this.animation.row = 1;                              // The row of the current frame being drawn
        this.animation.col = 1;                              // The column of the current frame being drawn
        this.animation.firstRow = 1;                         // The row of the frame to initialize the animation loop on
        this.animation.firstCol = 1;                         // The column of the frame to initialize the animation loop on
        this.animation.lastRow = 1;                          // The row of the frame to restart the animation loop on
        this.animation.lastCol = 1;                          // The column of the frame to restart the animation loop on

        this.frame = new Object();
        this.frame.width = 0;                               // Init image.onload
        this.frame.height = 0;                              // Init image.onload
        this.image.onload = () => {                                 // Calculates width and height of animation frame based on numRows, numColumns, spacing, and margin
            
            let imageWidth = this.image.width;
            let spriteSheetWidth = imageWidth - (2 * this.margin);
            let widthNoSpacing = spriteSheetWidth - this.spacing * (this.numCols - 1);
            let frameWidth = widthNoSpacing / this.numCols;

            let imageHeight = this.image.height;
            let spriteSheetHeight = imageHeight - (2 * this.margin);
            let heightNoSpacing = spriteSheetHeight - this.spacing * (this.numRows - 1);
            let frameHeight = heightNoSpacing / numRows;

            this.frame.width = frameWidth;
            this.frame.height = frameHeight;
        }

    }

    draw() {
        
        // Draw the frame at the current row and column.
        context.drawImage(
            this.image,                             // the entire image being loaded
            this.animation.col * this.frame.width,  // sx, x coordinate to begin crop
            this.animation.row * this.frame.height, // sy, y coordinate to begin crop
            this.frame.width,                       // swidth, width of cropped image
            this.frame.height,                      // sheight, height of cropped image
            this.position.x,                        // x coordinate where to place image on canvas
            this.position.y,                        // y coordinate where to place image on canvas
            this.frame.width,                       // the width to stretch/shrink it to
            this.frame.height                       // the height to stretch/shrink it to
        )
```

Here I create a new MoveableObject with position defined and then console.log() it. It shows position to be what I set it to. I copy/paste that declaration and change "new MoveableObject" to "new Sprite" (with a new variable name of course) and print that, and it shows position is undefined:

```
// Initializers for main()
const gravity = 0.8;
const player = new Sprite({
    imageSrc: './lib/img/template.png',
    numRows: 21,
    numCols: 4,
    spacing: 0,
    margin: 0,
    position: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
})
console.log(player)
const enemy = new MoveableObject({
    colorRGB: 'blue',
    width: 50,
    height: 150,
    position: {
        x: 150,
        y: 50
    },
    velocity: {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
    }
})
console.log(enemy)
const moveableObjects = [player, enemy];

// The main function of the script updates the game state every frame.
function main() {

    // When the game starts the canvas, then player, then enemy are rendered.
    context.fillStyle = 'black';
    context.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    player.draw();
    enemy.draw();
```

The error is raised on player.draw() and reads "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'x')"

Does anyone understand why this is the case? It seems to me like the error is maybe produced by not properly extending my class or using super() incorrectly to pass attributes, but I haven't found an example that proves that.

Comment: Your base class constructor is declared such that it expects to be passed a single parameter, an object with those properties that will be plucked out when it's called. However, your subclass calls it with *two* parameters, neither of which is the right sort of object. Probably `super({ position, velocity })` is what you need.

Comment: @Pointy Eureka, that worked! A simple solution and a (relatively) simple question. I hope this will get more upvotes so that others will see this, because it's less complicated than other similar questions on here and probably more relevant to beginners who frequent this website and are liable to make mistakes more like these.

Comment: Well, SO already has many-many questions like this. The problem is, each of them is very specific to the OP's code. And unfortunately, those who have sufficient knowledge to find & recognise this as a problem similar to theirs and apply the solution to their code do probably already know how to fix issues like this without searching in the first place... (I don't want to disappoint you -- I just think SO's format is not very well-suited for questions of this kind, which is a problem the site has to handle)